# Change overlapping of nodes in IHMC's CmapTools

Tags: file-format

I am creating diagrams using CmapTools (not strictly concept maps), and in one of these diagrams I would like to put overlapping nodes, like in the image below.

[image: Two white nodes, "4" and "3" are overlapping some green text nodes. "4" is below the green node, but "3" is above.]

Some of them are over the green node, some are below. I saw one of them changing "layers", but I didn't pay attention and can't reproduce the procedure.

Is there any way to make the "4" node be drawn over the green node like the "3"?

If it can be achieved by file-editting, it's fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to specify the order in which nodes are displayed in CmapTools. It will be available in a future version. For Cmap support, tweet to @cmaptools or use our forum at http://Cmapforum.ihmc.us